# Scrollbar issue in scrolledittext openlaszlo

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx

I am using scrolledittext class in my application the class is working perfectly fine in OL swf runtime but not in DHTML runtime. I am not able to see an activated scrollbar when i am typing in the scrolledittext.

I am using the following code

```
<canvas>
<include href="incubator/scrolledittext.lzx" /> 
<include href="lz/vscrollbar.lzx"/>
<include href="incubator/newvscrollbar.lzx"/>
<include href="incubator/newvscrollbar_resources.lzx"/>

           <button name="text">
           <handler name="onclick">
            canvas.sp.inp.onfocus.sendEvent();

           </handler>
           </button>
  <scrolledittext name="sp" x="50" y="50" 
                                 height="300" 
                                 width="400" 
                                 focusable="true"
                >    
           </scrolledittext>    
</canvas>
```

Am i missing something or is this a bug in DHTML runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a known bug, which has already been filed:

http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-10260 or http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-10217

http://jira.openlaszlo.org/jira/browse/LPP-10303, the JIRA issued you filed is probabably a duplicate of either LPP-10260 or LPP-10217.

Comment: Yes i was searching in the wrong place then only i found that bug